# Iterate through an associative array in while loop

Tags: php, arrays, while-loop, associative-array

**EDIT**
I have an associative array :

```
$formation_domains_info_array = array(
    'electrotechnique-electronique' => array(
        'title'     =>  'ÉLECTROTECHNIQUE - ÉLECTRONIQUE',
        'flechage'  =>  array(212, 213, 355),
    ),
    'informatique-infographie-cao-dao' => array(
        'title'     =>  'INFORMATIQUE - INFOGRAPHIE - CAO/DAO',
        'flechage'  =>  array(217, 218),
    ),
    'metiers-du-verre-horlogerie' => array(
        'title'     =>  'MÉTIERS DU VERRE - HORLOGERIE',
        'flechage'  =>  array(215, 224),
    )
);
```

I wanted to iterate through it this way :

```
while ($index < count($fdomains_array)) {
     echo $formation_domains_info_array[$index++] .'<br/>';
     $index++;
}
```

I am quite surprised to get "`Undefined offset 0`" as an error message.
Is it not possible to iterate that way through associative array in PHP?

Thanks in advance for your explanations.

Comment: `$index` is a number, your array key is a non-numeric string, so that certainly won't work.... use [foreach()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

Comment: Please enter the full example of iteration.

Comment: No, you cannot do this with an associative array, because behind the scenes, it's essentially using `$array[0], $array[1], $array[2]`...etc. You need to use `list` and `each` as arguments to the while statement. This is inefficient, however, and a for statement would be better in this case.

Comment: note : count($fdomains_array) is philosophically wrong in all cases / languages. You should do execution for count before while, else on every iteration it is recounted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to iterate an associative array using while, but just not this way. You'll need to leverage the `list` and `each` methods as arguments to the while statement.

```
while(list($key, $value) = each($formation_domains_info_array)):
    //do stuff here
endwhile;
```

But your best bet, would simply be a foreach loop.

```
foreach($formation_domains_info_array as $idx => $arr):
    //do stuff here
endforeach;
```

Comment: Thanks. Then it is not really possible. 
I edited my question, as I forgot to write how I actually went through the array in the while loop. 

The purpose was to be able to stop when a certain condition was met, not having to go through the whole array. I guess my only choice is `foreach` coupled with a `break` statement

Comment: or add another condition to the while loop